# Laravel Route::currentRouteName() is null

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-7

I need to use subdomain (and also custom domains) with a Laravel 7 project. This code was my initial starting point:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.eniston.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@show')->name('fe.home');
});
```

Users can create their own slug / subdomain, which in this case should be `{subdomain}`. The route is correctly fetching the group. But the problem is that `Route` is null.

Basically, I cannot use `get('/' ...)` because if I `dd(Route::currentRouteName())`, I get null. Just as a quick test, I did `dd(URL::current())`, which returned the correct url. If I use `get('/test' ...)`, this works fine.

So, this works:

```
Route::domain('{subdomain}.eniston.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/test', 'FrontendController@show')->name('fe.home');
});
```

I don't understand why the initial Route is null.

---

**Update:**

As it turns out, `dd(Route::currentRouteName())` always returns null. Even for non-subdomain routes. So basically, I'd need to overwrite my `/` route if a subdomain is visiting the page.

Comment: Can you give an example? e.g. if you go to URL `https://a.eniston.test/` and in the route handler you do `dd(request()->route())` what do you get?

Comment: @apokryfos It just returns null. But if I apply anything after the domain, like https://a.eniston.test/hello, it returns to correct route.